# QGIS adding two months to a date time

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have two columns one that has the BeginLigeSpanVersion and one that has the end LifeSpanVersion, both kind of noted into Date Time format. I said kind of because usually in the unfiltered unaltered state it looks like this in string format:

{ "DisplayValue": "2020-02-05T16:37:15.4534428+01:00", "Value": "2020-02-05T16:37:15.4534428+01:00" }

With the magic of this command it is converted to date time :

```
CASE WHEN  "beginLifespanVersion" Is NOT NULL 
THEN
to_datetime(string_to_array("beginLifespanVersion"  ,'"')[7])
ELSE
NULL
END
```

Now it took me a while to realise that the difference between the two dates is two months...kinda. I have posted a picture how it suppose to look like below. How do I do how do I add two months to this?

[image: h]

Comment: +1 is the difference from UTC in winter, +2 is the difference from UTC in summer (in Central Europe). So you needn't worry about this.

Comment: I see then what to do add two months?

Comment: After `to_datetime(string_to_array("beginLifespanVersion"  ,'"')[7])`, add `+ to_interval('2 months')`  (Please make sure to put a space between `2` and `months`).

Comment: Thank you solved it even though +1 does not change. I should not worry about it.